# angular.js:13424 ReferenceError: index is not defined when using factory method in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created an Angular factory, that I am then using in a controller. The factory contains a `delete` method that I am trying to use in my controller, however, I am seeing an error that says `index` is not defined. Previously, before I had a factory, and when everything was in the controller this function worked, but now `index` is no longer defined. I have read many answers on here, but cannot find an answer.

My code looks like as follows:

**js**

```
app.factory('addressFactory', function(){

    var addressFactory = {};
    addressFactory.addressBook = [];

    addressFactory.deleteAddress = function(index) {
        addressFactory.addressBook.splice(index, 1); 
        localStorage.setItem('addressBook', JSON.stringify(messages.addressBook)); 
    }

    return addressFactory;
})

.controller('testCtrl', ['$uibModal', 'addressFactory', function ($uibModal, addressFactory) {

     this.addressBook = addressFactory.addressBook;
     this.deleteAddress = addressFactory.deleteAddress(index);
}]);
```

**html**

```
<div ng-repeat="contact in ctrl.addressBook track by $index"> 
    <p>{{contact.name}}</p>
    <button ng-click="ctrl.deleteAddress($index)">Delete Contact</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
this.deleteAddress = addressFactory.deleteAddress(index);
```

to this :

```
this.deleteAddress = function(index){
    addressFactory.deleteAddress(index);
};
```

Comment: BOOM! Cheers for that!

Comment: @phantom no problem, glad I could help

Comment: Even function variable assignment would work  : 


`this.deleteAddress = addressFactory.deleteAddress;  
// note not this.deleteAddress = addressFactory.deleteAddress(index)`